# updating a variable using using the output from another variable

Tags: python

I am trying to add the value of "next_answer" to current_answer anytime a new calculation is done but when I run the code the next_answer doesn't get added to the current_answer.
Did I position the "current_answer += next_answer" wrongly? Please help me:)

```
#calculator
#Add
def add(n1, n2):
  return n1 + n2
#subtract
def subtract(n1, n2):
  return n1 - n2

#multiply
def multiply(n1, n2):
  return n1 * n2

#divide
def divide(n1, n2):
  return n1 / n2

operations = {
  "+": add,
  "-": subtract,
  "*":multiply,
  "/":divide,
}

num1 = int(input("What is the first number?: "))


for operation in operations:
  print(operation)
select_operator = input("Which operator do you want? Type +, - * or /")
num2 = int(input("What is the next number?: "))

operation_function = operations[select_operator]
answer = operation_function(num1, num2)
print(f"{num1} {select_operator} {num2} = {answer}")

continue_ = True
while continue_:
  current_answer = answer
  next_calculation = input(f"Type 'y' to continue calculating with                                 
{current_answer} or type 'n' to exit.:")
  if next_calculation == "y":
    select_operator = input("Which operator do you want? Type +, - * or /")
    next_number = int(input("What is the next number?:"))
    operation_function = operations[select_operator]
    next_answer = int(operation_function(current_answer, next_number))
    print(f"{current_answer} {select_operator} {next_number} = {next_answer}")
    current_answer += next_answer
  elif next_calculation == "n":
    continue_ = False
    print("Thanks for using my calculator")
```

Comment: set `current_answer = answer` before `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Note that every time you go through the while loop, you set `current_answer` to be `answer`, which is the first answer. So you are overriding your update to the first calculation.

See line `current_answer = answer`.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the content has been simplified, so refer to it as appropriate：

```
operations = {"+": lambda x, y: x + y, "-": lambda x, y: x - y, "*": lambda x, y: x * y, "/": lambda x, y: x / y}


select_operator = input("Which operator do you want? Type: +, - * or /：")
num1 = int(input("What is the first number?: "))
num2 = int(input("What is the next number?: "))

answer = operations[select_operator](num1, num2)
print(f"{num1} {select_operator} {num2} = {answer}\n")

while True:
    next_calculation = input(f"Type 'y' to continue calculating with {answer} or type 'n' to exit.:")
    if next_calculation == "y":
        preview_answer = answer
        select_operator = input("Which operator do you want? Type: +, - * or /：")
        next_number = int(input("What is the next number?:"))
        answer = operations[select_operator](answer, next_number)
        print(f"{preview_answer} {select_operator} {next_number} = {answer}")
    else:
        print("Thanks for using my calculator")
        exit()
    print()
```